# Keep USB on while computer is shut down

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, charging

We have recently bought a wireless mouse to replace our old one. The charging dock on our old one plugged into the mains, it also had USB to connect to the computer. Our new mouse only has a USB cable (i.e. it connects and charges via USB)

Is there any way to leave the USB slot *on* when the computer is Shut Down (not just Sleeping). The mouse dock is plugged into a USB 2.0 port on the tower.

So far:
I've been rooting around and have found this in the *Device Manager*:

[image: Device manager settings]

But I don't know if this is correct, and I'm not sure which of those many options my mouse is actually plugged into

I've also read *Supercharger* as some presumably 3rd party software to do it, but I'm sure there is a Windows based solution

Comment: Some computers have an option for the USB to remain powered when shutdown in the BIOS. It's not really something that Windows or the operating system *should* control.

Comment: In BIOS or by jumper settings. Or they always do it, or never.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was highlighted in the comments, this is not OS specific, but a BIOS problem.

The approach I took should work for most HP models from mid 2011 to at least the time of writing, as well as any computer running a similar BIOS, and probably others too

Firstly, use the *Fast Charging port* if your computer has one (see picture, lightning symbol, USB 2.0)

[image: Fast charging port symbol]

Enter BIOS, find the *hardware power* settings and enable:

> Fast Charging Port in S4/S5

All this means is that in S4/S5 states (Hybrid Shutdown and Shutdown respectively - S3 is sleep) the charging port will remain on.

This should then enable *dumb* devices to charge as normal (any device which you could plug into a wall socket - usb charger)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that. Since the ACPI turns off the power to the computer after Windows shuts down, all ports will be inactive. The computer's power must be on in order for the USB ports to receive power.

Comment: Most if not all modern boards support powered USB when the machine is “off”. The backplate will usually have a symbol or color the port red to indicate which it is. You can configure this in the BIOS.