# USB dongle refuses to work on startup when in USB dock

Tags: windows, usb, audio, drivers, usb-hub

I have a wireless headset with a USB-C dongle. I bought a USB-Hub so that I do not have to plug it into my laptop where it takes up either my only thunderbolt port or a USB port. It works well, but when it is plugged into the hub it will not work on startup and requires to be re-plugged. When it is plugged directly this does not occur. Is there any way to automatically "re-plug" the dongle? Maybe using some kind of a script?

I am using windows11 so ideally I would prefer something simple like a powershell command.

Extra info: The HUB is a powered USB3 hub. I specifically chose USB3 because it supposedly adds less latency than USB2.

Comment: At a guess, the fact that the hub stays powered on while the PC USB port power is shut might be the cause. Try using the hub *without* the external power supply (assuming the PC can supply sufficient current for the dongle), or try setting the USB power option to stay on while PC is shut (https://superuser.com/questions/1275374/keep-usb-on-while-computer-is-shut-down) . Simple to test, though only a possibility.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Nope, just tested it with adapter unplugged. Neither reboot nor shutdown/manual start had any effect.